# Stop openvz vps from resetting hostname and resolv.conf to default on reboot?

Tags: debian, ssh, configuration, vps, openvz

So ive found with several hosting companies that my vps plan will reset its hostname and dns resolve.conf files to their initial state after reboot, loosing any changes.

I suspect this is a openvz thing, but im not 100%

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that my latest host recommended to me that has worked well on different accounts:

First off it will be making use of command "chattr" so if you dont have that yet you can get it in e2fsprogs package

```
apt-get install e2fsprogs
```

Next you want to set the values you want in /etc/hostname and /etc/resolve.conf 
Then using chattr to make the files read only , even to root

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf /etc/hostname
```